# Get values with regex in JMeter Regular Expression Extractor

Tags: regex, jmeter

I try to get value between quote signs in `JMeter`, but I get back whole string in `myvar_1_g0` named variable instead of the value. Tester: https://regex101.com/r/aId5jo/2

Sample text: `LoadXMLString("Response", window.atob("SGVsbG8="));`

Regex: `LoadXMLString\("Response", window\.atob\(".*"\)\);`

Comment: Use `LoadXMLString\("Response", window\.atob\("([^"]*)"\)\);` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/aId5jo/4)) and get it via `myvar_1_g1`. Use  `$1$` as template

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Thanks, that solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a capturing group like this:

```
LoadXMLString\("Response", window\.atob\("([^"]*)"\)\);
                                          ^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aId5jo/4).

To get the captured value, use `myvar_1_g1` and the `$1$` value as template.